# Performance issues running kafacat over slow speed link

Tags: performance, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, kcat

I have weird performance issues with *fetch.max.message.bytes* parameter in *librdkafka* consumer implementation (version 0.11). I run some tests using kafkacat over slow speed network link (4 Mbps) and received following results:

- 1024 bytes = 1.740s
- 65536 bytes = 2.670s
- 131072 bytes = 7.070s

When I started debugging protocol messages I noticed a way to high RTT values.

```
|SEND|rdkafka| Sent FetchRequest (v4, 68 bytes @ 0, CorrId 8) 
|RECV|rdkafka| Received FetchResponse (v4, 131120 bytes, CorrId 8, rtt 607.68ms)
```

It seems that increase of *fetch.max.message.bytes* value causes very high network saturation, but it carries only single message per request.

On the other hand when I try kafka-console-consumer everything runs as expected (I get throughput 500 messages per second over the same network link).

Any ideas or suggestions where to look at?

Comment: I believe this might be a problem with librdkafka, can you file a github issue here https://github.com/edenhill/librdkafka/issues/new and provide the output from `-d protocol,msg,queue,fetch,topic,broker` where it seems to only use one message per request?

Answer (score 0):

You are most likely hitting [issue #1384](https://github.com/edenhill/librdkafka/issues/1384) which is a bug with the new v0.11.0 consumer. The bug is particularly evident on slow links or with MessageSets/batches with few messages.

A fix is on the way.